# Data.Data -- producing dataCast1 for an arity 2 type constructor (partially specialized)

Tags: generics, haskell, scrap-your-boilerplate

So Data.Map has `dataCast2` defined, which makes sense, as it has an arity 2 type constructor. `dataCast1` defaults to `const Nothing`. `dataCast2` is easily defined as `gcast2`.

For reference:

```
class Typeable a => Data a where
    dataCast1 :: Typeable1 t => (forall d. Data d => c (t d)) -> Maybe (c a)
    dataCast2 :: Typeable2 t => (forall d e. (Data d, Data e) => c (t d e)) -> Maybe (c a)
    ...

gcast1 :: (Typeable1 t, Typeable1 t') => c (t a) -> Maybe (c (t' a))
gcast2 :: (Typeable2 t, Typeable2 t') => c (t a b) -> Maybe (c (t' a b))
```

The question at hand is this: given everything in `Data.Data`, `Data.Typeable`, etc., and given an arity 2 type constructor for which `dataCast2` is defined (say, `Map`, or `(,)` ), is it possible to write a version of `dataCast1` that does the right thing for a partial specialization of this type constructor, either for one specific constructor at a time, or in general?

Intuitively, I think there should be a good solution, but my first few tries crashed and burned.

Comment: This looks like an interesting problem, but I think I'm going to need a little more background. First, a question. What exactly do you mean by "does the right thing for a partial application of this type constructor"? Type constructors can appear partially applied in the head of a class or instance declaration, however, anywhere else they must appear fully applied AFAIK.

Comment: @Sean Good point. I changed it to read "partial specialization". The point being to be able to call `myDataCast1` with a result of `Maybe (c (Int, a))` the same way one can call `dataCast1` with a result of `Maybe (c (Maybe a))`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but it might steer you in the right direction if it's not. It is written in a very similar style to the `gcast`, `gcast1`, and `gcast2` functions in the Data.Typeable library. For more details, "read the source, Luke".

```
myDataCast1 :: forall c t d e a.(Typeable d, Typeable e) => c (t d a) -> Maybe (c (t e a))
myDataCast1 x = r
   where
     r = case typeOf (getArg x) == typeOf (getArg (fromJust r)) of
           True  -> Just $ unsafeCoerce x
           False -> Nothing
     getArg :: c (t x a) -> x
     getArg = undefined
```

Using this function you can, for instance write `foo`

```
foo :: Typeable d => c (d, a) -> Maybe (c (Int, a))
foo = myDataCast1
```

Comment: close, but no :-). The tricky bit is to match how dataCast produces anything of type `Data a => Maybe (c a)` -- i.e. its result doesn't have any type constructors except for the `c`. To see why this is necessary, try playing around with `Data.Generics.Aliases` and consider why `ext1Q` can't be written (at least by me) with simply `gcast1` instead of `dataCast1`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/gmap2.ps) the way to implement dataCast1 is either as

```
dataCast1 f = gcast1 f -- for unuary type constructors
```

or

```
dataCast1 f = Nothing -- for non-unary type constructors
```

They haven't said that this is the only way to implement it, but it might be the case. Perhaps it's worth asking the authors? I think the core problem is that we can't partially apply type constructors. e.g. the following is not possible

```
data T a b = ...

instance Typeable a => Data (T Int) where
   dataCast1 f = ...
```

GHC will complain that T has not been applied to enough type arguments.

I can think of a work-around though. We define a newtype

```
newtype PairInt a = PairInt (Int, a) deriving Typeable

instance (Typeable a, Data a) => Data (PairInt a) where
  dataCast1 f = gcast1 f
```

It's pretty annoying but it does the job. But perhaps it doesn't fit with what you're trying to achieve.